# Get the list of Event Listeners that exist on an Html element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to get the list of event listeners that are already attached to the element. Right now I have tried using:

```
getEventListeners(el)
```

This works fine while using in Chrome. Otherwise, using this code in Javascript gives me the error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getEventListeners is not defined

Is there any alternate solution to it? Or the same method can be used in Javascript?

Comment: Check if your question doesn't have an answer somewhere else already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node-in-javascript-or-in-debugging

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+get+event+listeners+of+element+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.